# How to fix OOP Issue with opacity change in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to make pieces of what makes pygame into it's own separate classes/definitions. But when trying to set the opacity of an image, Instead of showing up as excepted, It starts from it's set opacity and lightens up until it reaches the maximum opacity possible.

I have tried to see if the opacity changes in the module that contains the game, and in the module that contains the classes. Yet they end up giving me the correct number that should be the number that is set for the opacity. And yes I have looked for anything that could possibly start adding up the opacity by mistake.

This is the piece of the code that i'm using to edit an image.

```
class PicEditor:

    def scale(Pic,scaleX,scaleY):
        Pic.blit = pygame.transform.scale(Pic.blit,(scaleX,scaleY))

    def opacity(Pic,opc):
        Pic.blit.set_alpha(opc)
        print(opc) #attempt at figuring out the problem
```

And this is the code that i'm trying to run.

```
while not crashed:
    display.gameLoopTop() #the usual game loop used ontop in pygame
    PicEditor.opacity(templatePic,opacityTemplate) #the issue
    PicEditor.scale(templatePic,displayX,displayY) #scaling an image (works fine)
    templatePic.blitIMG() #bliting the image
    display.gameLoopBottom() #the bottom of a game loop which includes the clock function and pygame display update
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The expected results are that the image will change it's opacity by 50 (opacityTemplate = 50), then that the image will fit the size of the screen (displayX,displayY) and then that it is blited.

Everything runs perfectly, except that the opacity of the image goes from it's number given- 50, and adds another 50 until it reaches the maximum opacity possible without crashing.